# How do you set up an array to hold '0's for empty locations so graphs(Highcharts) can format them correctly?

Tags: php, sql, pdo, highcharts

I'm trying to get my Highcharts graph to work. The Reason I'm having so much trouble with it this time is because I have to keep the program adaptable for future changes when it comes to my columns(named issues1 through 12).

The Goal is pretty simple, I just need to grab the issues between hours 1-12 during a certain time period, then create a graph.

[image: The Table Layout.]

[image: This is how the Graph comes out now.]

My idea Is that I should create a view that organizes the desired information because there is a lot more to that table that I left out, and then create an SQL to organize the data from there. Which I realize might be overkill, but I'm an intern and my supervisor probably did it to help make it simple for me.

[image: The View I'm calling on.]

There are 4 different places I need to use SQL to make the Table work.

- X-Axis
- Day shift numbers
- Swing shift numbers
- Night shift numbers

[image: This is what its supposed to look like with this information.]

So for my code The X-Axis, It works fine for just calling in the names.

```
 xAxis: {               
categories: [
 <?php
 foreach ($xAxisresult as $Xrow) {
    echo "'" . $Xrow['IssueName'] . "'" .  ',';
}
?>
]
```

I believe the Day/Swing/Grave SQL statements should all be similar so I'm just going to focus on one. But this is where the problem starts with how I have it set up. I tried to run an If statement were I compare the two arrays I have set up and try to match the IssueName Columns.

```
name: 'Day',
        data: [
            <?php
foreach ($Dresult as $Drow) {
    if ($Xrow['IssueName'] == $Drow['IssueName']){ 
    echo $Drow['Issues'] . ',';
}
else{
    echo $Drow['Issues'] . ',';
}
}
```

You guys can most likely see a lot of whats wrong here. But I need to make a loop or array that will find out that if there is an empty spot in the array and output a 0 so the data stays correct.

Sorry for the wall of Text, I just wanted to give you guys as much information as possible.

Comment: You have given a lot of information, and talked about what your requirements are. However, I don't see any questions. You should include the infromation passed to php (not as a picture but as code), the php you use to give this information to highcharts, and lastly the highcharts config. As it is now, there is a myriad of ways to "put 0 in empty spots", that can be solved in SQL, PHP, or javascript. Please clarify what exactly you are after, and what exactly is the problem in getting there. Having a look at how to create a [mcve] is probably a good idea as well.

Comment: add something related to question too . you want to set 0 at empty locations, tell about location and related to it, show x and y axis, what i understand from question can be done by sql or by jquery or by php

Comment: or add a jsfiddle would be easier

Comment: Ok my bad. I guess the simplest question is. How would i Get the data in my HighChart (shift/day/grave) to match up with with the X-axis Labels?

Comment: That is not a simple question though, you can do that in so many different ways. It depends heavily on how you want to do things, what your future plans are, and what language you are most comfortable in. As I said before, that can be achieved by SQL, PHP, or Javascript.  There are a lot of resources on google for this, for example this: https://blueflame-software.com/how-to-load-mysql-results-to-highcharts-using-json/ that I found. Getting your data through JSON is the preffered way to import data to highcharts.

Comment: Yah, you pretty much hit the nail on the head there. I just started php 2 months ago and I have only started learning Javascript/Jquery. I appriciate you show me the blueflame link and i will look into JSON right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question how to create an array that holds zero values and merge with the data array (I assume).

You can use array_fill to create the array with zeros, and use array_replace to replace with the data array.

```
$arr = array_fill(0, 10, 0); //[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

$data = [2 => 15, 5 =>10, 7 => 16]; // your data

$new = array_replace($arr, $data);
var_dump($new); // [0,0,15,0,0,10,0,16,0,0]
```

Comment: Oh cool! i think that might fix a couple of other problems im having also.All i got to do is change that layout to my work with my code and i think i will be able to get it! Thanks!